# How do insert data to content://media/external/audio/albumart through content resolver, if Mediastore.audio.media.data is deprecated?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to insert bitmap to `content://media/external/audio/albumart` through Content resolver. But after of running data don't insert and absent exceptions and errors. Later I observed that Mediastore.audio.media.data is deprecated for android. Tell me how fix it. Below example:

```
 private static void writeArtwork(Context context, Bitmap bmp, long albumId) {
    ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    Log.i(TAG, "Bytes: " + bytes.length);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("album_id", albumId);
    values.put("_data", bytes);
    Uri uri = res.insert(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), values);
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(uri));
}
```